# Python Grid Treasure Hunt

Tags: python, grid

I'm trying to make a game where the user inputs the values they want to move up/down and left/right and the grid reprints with the X in the correct position - it's a treasure hunt. When you input valid movements the program fails or puts the X in a random place. I think the problem might be to do with the fact I'm not sure what number each column and row is assigned.
Here's the relevant part of code:

## Creating the Board

```
Move = 0
from random import randint
GridSize = 8

board = []

for x in range(8):
    board.append(["O"] * GridSize)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print( " ".join(row))

Player_Row = GridSize - 1
Player_Col = 0

def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)
board[Player_Row][Player_Col] = "X"
print_board(board)
while 1:
    #  Player Moving Up #
    Player_Row_Add = 123
    while (0 >(Player_Row - Player_Row_Add) < (GridSize -1)):
        try:
            Player_Row_Add = int(input("How many squares up do you want to go?"))
        except ValueError as ex:
            print(ex)

    # Player Moving Down #
    Player_Col_Add = 123
    while (0 >(Player_Col_Add + Player_Col)> (GridSize -1)):
        try:
            Player_Col_Add = int(input("How many squares along do you want to go?"))
        except ValueError as ex:
            print(ex)






    Player_Row = Player_Row - Player_Row_Add
    Player_Col = Player_Col + Player_Col_Add
    board[Player_Row][Player_Col] = "X"
    Move = Move + 1
    print_board(board)
```

Comment: that comparison sounds strange `while (0 >(Player_Row - Player_Row_Add) < (GridSize -1)):`. We would need more information (error message / stacktrace)

Comment: If you're designing games in Python you might wanna check out the [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/about) module. It may save you from reinventing the wheel on some things :)

Comment: I was trying to get it so that the program only accepts moves that mean the X is not thrown off the grid. Because of the ordering of columns, it made more sense to have a subtraction sum than an addition. I have researched but I am still confused about how columns and rows are numbered in Python.

Comment: I wish I could but it's for school and we've been told not to use modules like that and to print the grids on the shell in the way I've done (but a little more successfully...)

Comment: use many `print()` to see what values you have in variables and which part of code is executed - you will see what's goining on in program.

Comment: to make code more readable put first all imports, then all functions and then other code. And use `lower_case` names.

Comment: you set `Player_Col_Add = 123` and then second `while` is not executed so you get `board[Player_Row][123] = "X"` - so you try to put in column number `123`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong both `while`.

This versions are easier to understand

```
while not (-1 < Player_Row - Player_Row_Add < GridSize):

while not (-1 < Player_Col + Player_Col_Add < GridSize):
```

Without `not` you would need

```
while (-1 >= Player_Row - Player_Row_Add) or (Player_Row - Player_Row_Add >= GridSize):

while (-1 >= Player_Col + Player_Col_Add) or (Player_Col + Player_Col_Add >= GridSize):
```